# Php code to play audio streaming in android not work

Tags: php, android, audio-streaming, live-streaming

hello I need your help I need the code to play audio streaming serve what I need is that when the person enter php page from your android mobile download mp3 player and sound in android prederterminado the way it is in this page http://s2.viastreaming.net/mobile.php?port=6520 prefectamente served well but I would do the same with this code works but I was told that the problem is that if the file but does not sound what the problem please if someone know the subject .. I need your help please

```
<?php 

header("Content-type: audio/mpeg"); 
header("Transfer-Encoding: chunked");
header("Transfer-Encoding: none"); 
header("Connection: close");

$sock = fsockopen($streamname,$port); 

$streamname = "193.17.192.13"; //IP
$port = "80"; // PORT
$path = "/;stream.mp3"; 


fputs($sock, "GET $path HTTP/1.0\r\n");
fputs($sock, "Host: $ip\r\n"); 
fputs($sock, "User-Agent: WinampMPEG/2.8\r\n"); 
fputs($sock, "Accept: */*\r\n"); 
fputs($sock, "Icy-MetaData:1\r\n"); 
fputs($sock, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");



fpassthru($sock); 

fclose($sock);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a close look at the data you are returning from your PHP script.  Your response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 25 Jan 2013 04:19:16 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze8
icy-notice1: <BR>This stream requires <a href="http://www.winamp.com/">Winamp</a><BR>
icy-notice2: SHOUTcast Distributed Network Audio Server/Linux v1.9.8<BR>
icy-name: Atmosfera 96.5 Grupo Emisoras Unidas
icy-genre: Rock
icy-url: http://www.atmosfera.fm
icy-pub: 1
icy-br: 64
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
```

The problem you likely have is that your are sending your stream with chunked encoding.  This is supported by later versions of Android (>2.3 I think), but not before.  Chunked encoding is also not compatible with many other players such as VLC and early versions of Winamp.

The simple solution is to make sure your server is sending back HTTP/1.0 responses, which do not use transfer-encoding.  I haven't tested this, but since you are using Apache, try this:

```
apache_setenv('force-response-1.0','true');
```

Also, remove your two `header()` calls with `Transfer-Encoding`.

Once this is done, test and see if it works.  By the way, you can use a tool such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) to easily see what is going on with your streams.